# Solucionar error development mode de asp net core

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, azure

Estoy tratando de publicar una aplicación web de asp net core 2.2 en azure. Aparentemente se publicó bien sin embargo cuando entro me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar que ya cambie la variable de entorno que dice ahí a Production en lugar de Development

Comment: Cabe mencionar que ya cambie la variable de entorno que dice ahí a Production en lugar de Development

Comment: Agrega mas informacion que version de asp.net core usas y en que ambiente estas publicando. Asegurate que en tu IIS si estas usando tengas la misma version de .net core que la usada en el desarrollo. Asegurate que IIS tenga permisos de accesso a la carpeta del sitio

Comment: 2.2 y es en azure

Comment: Si la publico en IIS nisiquiera funciona

Comment: Puedes agregar el error completo, accedes a algun recurso externo para tu sitio? digamos te conectas a BD

Comment: Pero las variables de entorno se tienen que cambiar en la maquina en la que has hecho el despliegue no en las opciones de debugging del proyecto, has cambiado la variable de entorno en la maquina en la que despliegas??

Comment: Gracias pero no va a ser necesario. En la clase startup.cs agregue esta línea :  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); y quite el if que valida si es development  environment o no y entonces eso me permitio ver cual era el error real que estaba ocurriendo.

Comment: ¿y lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: @fredyfx Correcto

Comment: Agrega la respuesta y luego de 24 horas márcala como aceptada :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionarlo agregue esta línea en la clase startup.cs  :

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

y borré el **if** que valida si es development environment o no y entonces eso me permitio ver cual era el error real que estaba ocurriendo.

Comment: Quiero creer que esto no es una solucion, si no un terrible parche momentaneo que despues sacaste.. decime que es asi.. por favor...